# Detect pre configured router IP address

Tags: windows, networking, router, ip

I received a pre-configured router (Juniper SRX240) for local intranet.
The router is configured with static IP and DHCP is not enabled.
The problem is that I don't have a clue what is the IP address configured, So I don't know how to set up the IP address for the PC (Windows 7) I directly connect to it.

I need to fill up IP, mask and default gateway(should be the router IP, right ?)

Is there a scanner which tries all options until it finds the right IP ?
Maybe there's another approach ?

BTW, the console interface for the router requires a special cable I don't have.

Comment: Why don't you ask the person (company) that supplied the router?

Comment: Why do you think you need a special cable? You should be able to to access the router interface with a normal ethernet cable.

Comment: @DavidPostill he's on vacation :(

Comment: @DavidPostill I can't use the eternet cable if I don't know the router IP, chicken and the egg thing...

Comment: Does this help? http://www.techspot.com/guides/287-default-router-ip-addresses/

Answer (score 1):

Download wireshark, disconnect all network cables from the router, and disconnect your computer from the internet. Connect a cable between the router LAN port and your computer. Use Wireshark to capture packets between the two devices - one or more of those packets will contain the routers IP address.

Comment: There is traffic, but it doesn't contain the router IP, it's Spanning tree STP frame, which I don't see any IP information on it.

Comment: restart the router whilst scanning -it will have to broadcast jt's address at some stage. Would it be ipv6 only?

Comment: does the mac address in the packet correspond to the mac address of the router?

Answer (score 0):

Look for the manual page for that particular router and check if the router assigns itself a fixed IP. Also check the router top, back and bottom for a stick containing its IP.